# Windows utility à la Android to type accented characters in capital?

Tags: windows, keyboard

As an alternative to the cumbersome ALT+(ANSI code) in Windows, Android provides a neat solution to type European accented characters in capital:

[image]

The menu is displayed by long-pressing the letter.

Is there a utility for Windows that does the same thing?

Thank you.

--

Edit: I know about [Keyxpat](http://keyxpat.com/en/how), but I'd rather pick a character from a window rather than relying on the number of sound ticks played by the sound card.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as we all know, holding down a letter key will simply type that letter over and over. I don't know if there's any way to change that. My initial reaction is to use character map, but I can see that being just as cumbersome as ALT codes depending on how often you need accents.

My solution would be to set up an international keyboard. Below are instructions for Vista, I assume they're similar enough for your Windows OS, even though you didn't say which you're using. From http://www.studyspanish.com/accents/typing.htm :

> **Windows Vista**
>   1. Start-->Control Panel-->Clock, Language, Region-->Change Keyboards
>   2. New Window: Click the Change Keyboards button
>   3. New Window: Click the Add button
>   4. Select United States-International keyboard
>   5. Click OK
>   6. From drop down menu (Default Input Language) select United States International
>
> **Using the U.S. - International Keyboard** 
> If you followed the above
>   directions carefully, your keyboard will now react slightly
>   differently than it did before. First of all, notice that if you
>   strike the single apostrophe (') key, nothing happens. To type the
>   single apostrophe now, you must strike the single apostrophe key and
>   then strike the space bar. When you strike the spacebar, the
>   apostrophe will appear.
>
> The next thing to note is that the quotes (") key behaves the same way
>   as the apostrophe key. You must first strike the quotes key and then
>   strike the space bar in order to create the (") symbol. These two
>   minor inconveniences are more than made up for by the ease with which
>   you can now type the special characters.
>
> To type the special characters, two keystrokes are required. To type
>   the á, you need only strike the apostrophe key and then the letter a.
>   The other characters are just as easy:
>
> •á = ' + a 
> •é = ' + e 
> •í = ' + i 
> •ó = ' + o 
> •ú = ' + u 
> •ñ = ~ + n 
> •ü =
>   " + u 
> To type the special punctuation characters, you need to hold
>   down on the Alt key while you strike the appropriate punctuation mark.
>   On some keyboards, only one of the two Alt keys will work for this.
>
> •¡ = Alt (hold down) + ! 
> •¿ = Alt (hold down) + ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If that means switching to a different keyboard layout than the one people are used, it won't do, though.

I'll check what it takes to display a window and let users pick a character.